# Making a copy of an object Dynamically?

Tags: java, copy, hashmap

My application stores my web service responses into WeakHashMap.
In my application I manipulate the data coming back from the web service in UI, and since the objects are being referenced it also modifies the reference (In my weak hashmap).

Is there a way to store a copy of the objects into my hashmap instead of a reference, without having to implement Clonable on every single Model object in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) allows serialization with minimal effort. It's also should be very efficient as uses direct memory copying with a help of `sun.misc.Unsafe`. From their quick start:

```
Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
SomeClass someObject = ...
SomeClass copy1 = kryo.copy(someObject);
SomeClass copy2 = kryo.copyShallow(someObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialization/deserialization to do that.

Comment: ...and that requires to implement `Serializable` (and/or `Externalizable`).

Comment: Yes, I don't want to have to do this every time I add a new Model

Comment: the only other possibility are complete ugly unsafe hacks, which require you to make strong assumptions about the internal memory layout of objects and may break with the next minor hotspot update ..